# System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity (User.Identity) fails to populate the claims as sent by Azure AD

Tags: azure, owin, openid-connect, claims

I have used OpenIdConnect for Azure AD authentication.

My application is multitenant. I have used Azure AD for Application authentication.

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {   ..other fields..   }
```

On successful signin, after the application is built and started, it works fine. ClaimPrincipal is properly populated with the data sent by Azure AD.

It terribly fails to populate when the same application is run in different browser.

Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance,
Rahul

Comment: You may want to elaborate more on the following statement - `It terribly fails to populate when the same application is run in different browser.`. Please describe what you mean by `it terribly fails` and also tell us in which browser it worked and in which browser it failed.

Comment: After I build my application and choose a default browser IE or chrome, my application receives the Claims returned by Azure AD as issuer. Now ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.IsAuthenticated becomes true, if checked in any of the Controller/Action.
I copy the same url and paste in other browser(non default browser). Authentication token is still received but, ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.IsAuthenticated becomes false in Controller/Action.
This is a very unusual behavior. 
Kindly Suggest me

Answer (score 2):

the issue in my application was because of the behavior of Owin, the middleware I used in my application.

Issue with the Owin:
In OWIN, the response headers collection is the primary storage location for response cookies. System.Web however stores response cookies in a separate HttpContext.Response.Cookies collection and then writes them out to the Response.Headers collection just before sending the response. This can cause a conflict if OWIN if both approaches are used on the same request, as the Response.Cookies collection will overwrite any cookies set via the OWIN response headers.

Unfortunately there is no general purpose solution to the problem. The set-cookie header from OWIN cannot be reliably re-parsed and redirected through System.Web's Response.Cookies collection. Nor can the OWIN components write directly to System.Web's Response.Cookies collection by default as this would compromise their platform independence.

The Workarounds:
Reconfigure the CookieAuthenticationMiddleware to write directly to System.Web's cookie collection

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // ...
            CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
        });
```

The  SystemWebCookieManager class definition as follows:

```
public class SystemWebCookieManager : ICookieManager
{
    public string GetRequestCookie(IOwinContext context, string key)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        var webContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
        var cookie = webContext.Request.Cookies[key];
        return cookie == null ? null : cookie.Value;
    }

    public void AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
        }

        var webContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);

        bool domainHasValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Domain);
        bool pathHasValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Path);
        bool expiresHasValue = options.Expires.HasValue;

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);
        if (domainHasValue)
        {
            cookie.Domain = options.Domain;
        }
        if (pathHasValue)
        {
            cookie.Path = options.Path;
        }
        if (expiresHasValue)
        {
            cookie.Expires = options.Expires.Value;
        }
        if (options.Secure)
        {
            cookie.Secure = true;
        }
        if (options.HttpOnly)
        {
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        }

        webContext.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
    }

    public void DeleteCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, CookieOptions options)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
        }

        AppendResponseCookie(
            context,
            key,
            string.Empty,
            new CookieOptions
            {
                Path = options.Path,
                Domain = options.Domain,
                Expires = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            });
    }
}
```

It no longer gave me any sing-in issue.

Comment: We are relatively sure that this fixed an issue where our OWIN Authentication cookies were not getting written to the browser, so our OpenID Connect middleware kept sending us back to the identity provider. A sincere thank you for this excellent write-up and additionally for the code sample that solves the problem.

Comment: There already exists a SystemWebCookieManager in package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, which is a mandatory package if you want to use OWIN with old System.Web.

Answer (score -1):

WindowsIdentity should be used only if your application is authenticating using integrated authentication. However here you are using OpenID Connect, hence you should only work with ClaimsPrincipal and ClaimsIdentity.

Comment: I am using  ** ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.IsAuthenticated **  in my Contoller/Action for checking the current signed in user is authenticated.

I becomes true when control returns to Contoller/Action from Start.Auth.cs after successful authentication received from Azure AD.

But, it becomes false with the same case when the same url is hit from any non default browser.

Comment: What is a "non default" browser?

Comment: if i run app in debug mode and app opens in IE,then on login authentication is successful and claims are retrieved in controller action. Now if I copy-paste the same localhost url to chrome (non default browser) then authentication is successful but claims are empty. We are using code sample of Dushyant Gill as mentioned in this link - https://github.com/dushyantgill/VipSwapper/tree/master/CloudSense

Comment: That must be some issue with the debugger and async code. Did you try to do a response.write to see if the code actually succeeds?

Comment: This application is hosted on Azure. Upon restarting the webapp, it runs as expected. Now if you open this in any other browser or clears the history of current browser. Claims are not populated even if the AD claims are received in startup.auth.cs

If you kindly share with me your email ID, I can share the necessary details so that you can have quick look at the behavior

Comment: Earlier you spoke about localhost, now you referee to Ana sure hosted application. I am not following

Comment: Actually the behavior is same whether I host it in Azure or I do that in localhost.